# Statements with and without parentheses

Tags: php, syntax

I'm currently learning PHP, and I've seen a couple of commands written with, and some without parentheses. I've had a look online but I could not seem to find an explanation as to why.

The sort of thing I'm talking about is:

```
include "header.php";
```

vs:

```
include ("header.php");
```

I've also seen the same thing with `echo` commands. Could someone explain the differences of these to me?